# Capture Frame from Video.js with Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, video.js

I'm attempting to fade out a Video.js video by capturing the current frame with canvas, create an image, doing all the player changes etc under the image and then fade out the image.

I can't seem to access the video via Canvas, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

Here's the code

```
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);
     var dataURL = thecanvas.toDataURL();

        //create img
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', dataURL);

        //append img in container div
        document.getElementById('body').appendChild(img);
```

Video is created thus:

```
             <video id='video' class='video-js' preload controls>
             <source src='http://example.com/video.mp4"' type='video/x-m4v' />
             </video>
```

Video is all running fine etc.

To dispose of the video I use

```
    var player = videojs('video');  
    player.dispose();
```

And assume this would be a better selector, however chucking 'player' into the `context.drawImage` after it's been declared doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by using the children array.

```
context.drawImage(video.children_[0], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Also, don't rely on `video.width` and `video.height`.  They don't seem to update.  Use `video.currentDimension("width")` and `video.currentDimension("height")` instead.

Answer (score -1):

It seems it's not possible with Video.js I've switched to Popcorn and using https://github.com/rwaldron/popcorn.capture to get the frames. This is working.